# Matlab : cannot get the values of a field in a struct

Tags: matlab, struct, field

I am encountering a rather weird problem. I have a big struct imported from a .mat file (it's an EEG recording):

[image: struct file]

Now let's assume I want to plot one field, I need to get the values in this field.
However, when I do this:

`fieldE1 = EEG.('00 E1');`

fieldE1 only becomes the last value of the field : [image].

If I just write in the console `EEG.('00 E1')`, it returns this :

```
ans =

  -12.5850 


ans =

  -12.5790


ans =

  -12.5760


ans =

  -12.5820


ans =

  -12.5890


ans =

  -12.5880


ans =

  -12.5880


ans =

  -12.5860
```

On and on and on for all the values. Which explains why fieldE1 only returned the last value. I have the same behaviour when I use `getfield(EEG, '00 E1')` .

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Subscript references to a field in a struct array will return a [comma-separated list](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html).  The list must be captured in array delimiters upon assignment to be used as an array:

```
fieldE1 = [EEG.('00 E1')];
```